# .NET 8 Core use Dictionary<Uri, Uri> in appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, appsettings

I use IOptions pattern for some of my classes as a configuration. And I need to use `Dictionary<Uri, Uri>` inside this options class:

```
public class CdnOptions
{
    public const string CONFIG_SECTION_NAME_S = "CdnTransformationOptions";

    public bool EnableCdnTransformations { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> CdnTransformRules { get; set; } = [];
}
```

and this is how I bind these options:

```
services.AddOptions<CdnOptions>().Bind(configuration.GetSection(CdnOptions.CONFIG_SECTION_NAME_S))
            .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

The *appsettings.json* contains data as follows:

```
CdnTransformationOptions": {
 "EnableCdnTransformations": true,
 "CdnTransformRules": {
   "https://localhost:7021": "https://cdn.mydomain.com"
 }
},
```

But however I change json I get an empty dictionary. I also tried to use simple `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of `Dictionary<Uri, Uri>`, but get same result.
What's missing in here?

Comment: hope you didn’t try to use Dictionaty but Dictionary :)

Comment: I tried, and it's empty too! )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the ':' character that the addresses contain, it is not allowed in keys

read more here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42643